# How to return distinct values and their count?

Tags: php, mysql, select, count, distinct

What I'm trying to do is (hopefully) simple, but I just don't quite have the right syntax. I'd like to return all distinct values in a table with a count of how many records for each value.

So, in PHP, I've got:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT tagName FROM tagTable");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo("<p>" . $row['tagName']) . "</p>");
}
```

This works well. The distinct values are returned! But now how do I get each distinct value's count to display as well? I would want something to the effect of:

```
echo("<p>" . $row['tagName']) . $tagCountGoesHere . "</p>");
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to get that using the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT tagName, count(tagName) AS tagCount FROM tagTable GROUP BY tagName
```

Comment: Okay... I'll give that try. But then how do I display the count in the echo statement?

Comment: As you normally with the title tagCount. eg: echo $row['tagCount'];

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT tagName, count(*) as TagCount 
FROM tagTable 
group by tagname
```

Comment: Wouldn't be better to backtick-escape `Count` in order to avoid confusion due to MySQL function name case-insensitiveness?

Comment: @redShadow: you could eb right, I don't use MySQL; I'll rename

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT tagName, COUNT(*) FROM tagTable GROUP BY tagName
```

Comment: DISTINCT is unnecessary when using a GROUP BY clause.