# How can I select a Distinct value and then order by amount returned using mysql and PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Okay so I tried using the solution listed on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348024/how-to-return-distinct-values-and-their-count), and I got some of it working but not exactly all of it.  I am trying to Display Distinct results and then order by the amount of the returned results.  Soo if an ID had results for 4 surveys, it would display 4.  Obviously I can do this `myql_num_rows` However, I do not know how to ORDER BY that amount, so it will display as...
    4
    3
    2
    1
Instead of..
    2
    4
    1
    3

Here is What I have so far, I think my Select statement is correct, I just need to echo it out correctly.

```
<?php
$query_db = ("SELECT DISTINCT SGSID FROM SGresult WHERE SGFACemail = '$email'");
$result = mysql_query($query_db, $surveys) or die(mysql_error());


$i = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

$SGSID = $row['SGSID'];
//INSERTED MODIFIED SELECT STATEMENT HERE
$query_check = ("SELECT SGpID, count(*) AS numCount FROM SGresult WHERE SGFACemail = '$email' AND  SGSID = '$SGSID' GROUP BY SGpID");

$result_c = mysql_query($query_check, $surveys) or die(mysql_error());
$row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result_c);
$SGpID = $row2[3];
echo $row2['numCount'];

//tried num_rows statement to return value of numCount
//$num_rows2 = mysql_num_rows($result_c, $row2['numCount']);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result_c);

$query_name = ("SELECT * FROM SGsurveyID WHERE SGSID = '$SGSID'");


$result_F = mysql_query($query_name, $surveys) or die(mysql_error($surveys));
$name_row = mysql_fetch_row($result_F);

<?php echo $row2['numCount'];  //this returns results, but not the amount of rows 
  $i++;?>

  <tr>
        <td><?php echo $i;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $name_row[1];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $num_rows;  ?></td>
        <td> <?php echo $row2['numCount']; ?></td>
      </tr>
      <?php


}
```

So to recap I basically trying to GROUP BY AND ORDER BY the number of rows returned in that DISTINCT result.

Thanks again as always for your help and pointers. Please forgive the messy code.

Answer (score 0):

use `SELECT DISTINCT SGSID FROM SGresult WHERE SGFACemail = '$email' ORDER BY SGSID desc`

Comment: That broke the entire php page, I assume you meant for me to insert that in the first query that I have listed?

Answer (score 0):

You're right in wanting to use group by and order by together.

I don't think mysql is to strict about group/order by syntax but let me know if this doesn't work, i'm a little rusty.

```
SELECT SGpID
  , count(*) AS numCount
FROM SGresult
WHERE SGFACemail = '$email' 
  AND  SGSID = '$SGSID' 
GROUP BY SGpID
ORDER BY numCount desc
```

This is for the query labeled by "`//INSERTED MODIFIED SELECT STATEMENT HERE`". I'm pretty sure you could get all that you're after from one query but I don't quite understand exactly what you're trying to do nor can I make out what your schema looks like.